# Building a nested array based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a nested array that I want to process into another nested array based on a value in the original.

Here's my original array, it's nested because I'll introduce other values later.

```
$dataArray = array (
    0 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058726"
    ),
    1 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058086"
    ),
    2 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058086"
    ),
    3 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058087"
    ),
    4 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058087"
    ),
    5 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058088"
    ),
    6 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058089"
    ),
    7 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058089"
    ),
    8 => array(
            "adgroupid" => "5426058090"
```

Here's the result I'm currently getting, **note the strings in Array numbers 1 & 2 should be nested in the same array, like in 3 & 5**.

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '5426058726' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '5426058086' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '5426058086' (length=10)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '5426058087' (length=10)
      1 => string '5426058087' (length=10)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '5426058088' (length=10)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '5426058089' (length=10)
      1 => string '5426058089' (length=10)
  6 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '5426058090' (length=10)
```

Here's my code, I need to use the if statement because at a later stage I want to introduce another argument:

```
$newdataArray = array();
$j = 0; // Set value of working variables
$adgroupidcheck = 0;

foreach ($dataArray as $value) { // Loop through the array

    if( $adgroupidcheck != $value['adgroupid'] ) { // Check $adgroupidcheck
        $newdataArray[][] = $value['adgroupid']; // Create a new nested array
        $j ++; // increment $j
    } else {
        $newdataArray[$j][] = $value['adgroupid'];  // Add to the current array
    }
    $adgroupidcheck = $value['adgroupid']; // Set $adgroupidcheck
}
```

So my problem is that my code only works after the first instance of the array check loop hasn't worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `foreach($dataArray as $item) $new[$item['adgroupid']] []= $item['adgroupid'];` does the trick, but could you explain why you need an array like this (n times the same string)?

Comment: Are the entries with the same value always consecutive?

Comment: Thank you, Yes entries with the same value will always be consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just pre-increment your `$j` value so it get added as the correct array. Otherwise it's sent to the next one, just make a quick trace.

```
if( $adgroupidcheck != $value['adgroupid'] ) { 
    $newdataArray[++$j][] = $value['adgroupid']; 
} else {
    $newdataArray[$j][] = $value['adgroupid'];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($dataArray as $value) { 

        if( $adgroupidcheck != $value['adgroupid'] ) { 
            $newdataArray[][] = $value['adgroupid']; 
            $j ++; // increment $j

        } else {
            $j--; //decrease j which was incremented after inserting one value  
            $newdataArray[$j][] = $value['adgroupid']; 
            $j++; // increment it again for it's original or new index

        }
        $adgroupidcheck = $value['adgroupid']; 
    }
```